# Prepending class names with superfluous names that could be in the namespace

Tags: c#

I am looking to see if this could come back to bite me in ways I did not anticipate. Right now I have 3 classes (example classes), which live in the same namespace.

```
 SqlServer.SqlServerConnectionSettings
 SqlServer.SqlServerCredentials
 SqlServer.SqlServerInstance
```

Later down the line I would also plan to have others like below.

```
 SqlLite.SqlLiteConnectionSettings
 SqlLite.SqlLiteCredentials
 SqlLite.SqlLiteInstance
```

I'm starting to think it would be easier to

```
 SqlServer.ConnectionSettings
 SqlServer.Credentials
 SqlServer.ServerInstance
```

Where collisions are handled only when ambiguous, by appending the namespace like above.

My only concern is that most code I see is prepended like my first example. Is there anyone that has gone and removed the prepended text from their codebases and found it improved or degraded readability?

Comment: What do you mean by `functionality`? Speed? Development time? Developer sanity?

Comment: Personally, I try to avoid prefixing unless the class name would wind up being so generic that it could easily cause confusion.  I think 'ConnectionSettings', 'Credentials' and 'ServerInstance' could meet that criteria, since lots of things require connecting with credentials to a server.

Comment: "that most code I see" - I think only in the ADO.NET providers. It's a pattern with a limited scope. But your classes seem to be inside that scope, so go with option 1.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I changed it to readability as ultimately it is the only metric that matters in this case.

Comment: @DanBryant True, but then how many things need connections to a server in the same scope, which I think is what this comes down to, that is better management of scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using the method you're suggesting for a while now and prefer it to the prepended style you're referring to.  I think it makes the code cleaner easier to read and have not run into any collisions in our projects.  I also think it's important to make your namespace very descriptive without being superfluous...*DataAccess.Database.SqlServer.ConnectionSettings*.

Comment: I am going to try your suggestion of more descriptive namespaces along with removing the prepended names. It is interesting that you have not yet had collision issues, although not surprising. I have a small project I can try it on to see how I go.